# Proxy cannot resolve name "localhost"

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, localhost

When I am connected to the proxy at work, and I call localhost as the protocol or .local as the top-level domain, I get the error from the proxy that the DNS could not resolve the name "localhost". I assume the proxy just needs to be configured to loopback when it encounters localhost. But why is localhost pinging the DNS at all? Why doesn't it loop back when I use localhost before it even leaves the machine?

Comment: What do you mean by "I call localhost"? Is the loopback interface configured correctly? On what kind of machine are you trying to ping the loopback?

Comment: The localhost as viewed by the proxy, is the proxy, which will conflict with your systems view of the localhost which is your system. So what is the point.

Comment: Selenium uses localhost. It also needs to access the internet. So I get the proxy error "cannot resolve localhost". Yes I am also trying to troubleshoot the proxy (Network Engineering was worthless and deleted my post)

Comment: Have you spoken with your IT staff? ARE you the IT staff?

Comment: I am a developer who is in contact with the networking team.